# How to prevent screen from terminating when command in window terminates

Tags: gnu-screen

When running 'screen ls' the screen stops with the text `[screen is terminating]`. I would like screen to keep the session alive and reattach to it to see the output of `ls`.

Of course the real thing is that I don't run `screen ls`, but rather a `screen fsck ...`, so I would like to ensure that the screen is not terminating when this command is finished.

I would love to have an answer that is useful for an already existing running screen session, so some interactive keys like `C-a ...` or `C-a :` (Enter command line mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enter the `zombie kr` command after typing <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>, to make a running `screen` keep the window open after the command finishes.  The `kr` part is specifying what keys you want to use to control the window after its command has finished -- in this case, "k" to kill/close the window, or "r" to restart the command.

Comment: +1 for clarification that you could do this on the fly without editing your `.screenrc`.

Comment: zombie kr onerror - this is the syntax to leave zombie screen only when exit code is > 0. I wasn't able to do it. Screen stays open even if exit is 0. When I resurrect (restart) the process it exits cleanly if 0. Someone soled this?

Comment: @AntonValqk - you should open a new question; it will be a lot more visible and you'll get better answers.

Comment: Just to report. Debian version of screen  4.3.1-1 works fine. If I start screen -d -m ./exit.sh 0 && screen -d -m ./exit.sh 1 then I see only 1 screen (the second one) as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Can't you just start screen first and run fsck inside your screen session?

Anyway, add this to your `~/.screenrc`:

```
zombie kr
verbose on
```

and then screen will leave your zombie session open.  You can then hit `r` to resurrect your session although in this case it will just run your command all over again which you probably don't want.  Probably what you want to do is then hit `ctrl-A <esc>` to enter the screen scrollback mode and browse back in your previous output.

Comment: Yes, I could. I was just in the situation, where I already had started screen in the non-optimal way... anyway doing as you suggest may result in the shell (say bash) doing an auto-logout so it will just postpone the problem.